Woocommerce place order button state once clicked, add text
When the place order button is clicked on my woocommerce site it takes a few seconds to complete the order, the user can see that the wheel turning to show the script is running. I am looking for a solution to add the text "please wait" under the turning wheel, so that my customer doesn't leave.
I tried to add this code as a hook that was here on the site, but it doesn't work for me.
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_checkout_jquery_script' );
function custom_checkout_jquery_script() {
  if ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) :
?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery( function($){
      jQuery('form.checkout').on('submit', function(event) {
        jQuery('button#place_order').text('Please Wait');
        event.preventDefault();
      });
  });
</script>
 <?php
  endif;
}

Turning wheel without text

I tried your code and works but it does not restore the original text if there is validation or any error occurs. So, to overcome this issue you can try the following code:
function custom_checkout_jquery_script() {
    if(is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url()){
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            // Change the text of the Place Order button during AJAX request
            $(document).on('click', '#place_order', function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.data('original-text', $this.text()); // Store original text
                $this.text('Please Wait'); // Set loading text

                $(document.body).on('checkout_place_order_success checkout_error', function() {
                    $this.text($this.data('original-text')); // Restore original text
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
    }
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'custom_checkout_jquery_script');

Add the above code in the child theme's functions.php
Try the following CSS to add text to the loader or spinner:
.woocommerce .blockUI.blockOverlay:before {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    content: "Please wait...";
    -webkit-animation: none;
    -moz-animation: none;
    animation: none;
    line-height: 1;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.95);
    color: #000;
    z-index: 999;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

Code tested and worked

Thank you for your code.
i tried it and put in my child-theme, file functions.php. The result is the same, no text is displayed. Turning wheel only.  I tried detele the cache.
I have: Wordpress 6.6.1 Theme Astra Pro 4.7.3 Woocomerce 9.1.4
Thanks for help.

You can see the turning wheel without the text above.

Apparently there was a misunderstanding here. Now I noticed that your code works. It will change the text of the button when the customer places an order. But the customer does not see this change, because the screen changes color to transparent and the button is not visible. In the foreground of the page, there is a spinning wheel in the middle indicating that the page is doing something - and here under the spinning wheel I would like to insert text, please wait.

I updated the answer, try the CSS code to add text in the spinner.
